# Cannot format code

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

I am trying to format the code from the link using the Stack Exchange app but when I cut and paste the code wall the spaces get removed and the hash marks disappear in the output.

How can I fix it? How can I properly format the code in my post?

[Lexicographic permutation list](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/106872/102862)

I am trying to copy a code file from GitHub to Stack Exchange, and the link to GitHub is in my answer below my post.

Answer (score 2):

You've used the 'blockquote' mode, not the code formatting mode.

The easiest nowadays is just to put ```` ``` ```` before and after the code block, like I did in the edit I just suggested to your post.

[image]